# how to create a EF data model like a sql server view

Tags: entity-framework

I need to create a model of union  of several sql server tables and i have to get ability of

insert , select , update and delete ...

```
(id like to use the model as same as any other model)
```

any suggestions ?

thanks for reading.

Edit: i tried sql server view but got the fallowing error when i want to insert to sql server view:

Msg 4406, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Update or insert of view or function 'viewName' failed because it contains a derived or constant field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create database view + stored procedures for insert, update and delete. You will map the view as a new entity and map imported stored procedures to insert, update and delete operations for that entity.

You actually don't need the database view - you can write the query directly to EDMX by using [DefiningQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738450.aspx) but it requires manual modification of EDMX. Default EF tools will delete your manual modification once you run Update from database again.

Even with defining query you still need those stored procedures. There is no other way to make entity based on defining query (view is also imported as defining query) updatable.

Comment: :Update or insert of view or function 'viewName' failed because it contains a derived or constant field. Thanx

Comment: You cannot update the view, you must update tables directly - that is why you need those stored procedures. They must implement a logic to know what records in tables used to construct your view must be updated, inserted or deleted.